# Can we pass private variavbles as function arguments?

Tags: c++, class, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am just a beginner in C++. I am a bit confused here regarding whether is it possible to pass a private pointer variable as a function argument. 
I have a function named `insert` which has the following prototype:

```
bool TreeDB::insert(TreeNode *tn,DBentry *newEntry);
```

In my program I used the following line: `insert(root,newEntry)` where `root` is a `TreeNode*` but the debugger stops working inside this function as soon as it hits the following line:

```
tn=new TreeNode(newEntry);
```

Here's the function declaration:

```
bool TreeDB::insert(TreeNode *tn,DBentry *newEntry){
    if(tn==NULL){
        tn=new TreeNode(newEntry);
        return true;
    }
    else if(newEntry->getName() == tn->getEntry()->getName())
        return false;
    else{
        if(newEntry->getName() > tn->getEntry()->getName())
            return insert(tn->getRight(),newEntry);
        else
            return insert(tn->getLeft(),newEntry);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion regarding fixing this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that root is a valid pointer and variable?

Comment: yeah, root in the only private variable in TreeDB

Comment: If you were not allowed to use a `private` variable in this way the compiler would slap you down long before you got a runable program. You have a logic problem of some sort. Post more code and maybe we can help you sort it out.

Comment: *Stops working* means nothing. Give the error message or better describe what happens.

Comment: i just added my function declaration

Comment: Interesting fun fact: `tn` is a pointer to a `TreeNode`, so a `TreeNode` has been passed by reference, but the pointer itself is passed by value and copied into `insert`. This means if you assign a dynamically allocated `TreeNode` to `tn` only `tn` knows about it and when `tn` goes out of scope at the end of `insert` the `TreeNode` will be leaked. The variable the calling function passed into `insert` will not get this new `TreeNode`. It's lost.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the insert function other than my previous comment. What does `TreeNode(DBentry *)` look like, or better, can we have an [mcve]? Well can other folk have the MCVE? I need to hit the sack.

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically allocate `tn` to `TreeNode` without leaking at the end?

Comment: Pass `tn` as a reference to a pointer: `bool TreeDB::insert(TreeNode *& tn,DBentry *newEntry)`

Comment: Hmmm. I needed to do a rethink there. yahoo, you need to actually insert the new `TreeNode` into the tree, currently your insert doesn't actually build the tree, so my earlier comment about nothing being wrong with `insert` is utter BS. `insert` currently does not insert. Quick hack is to make `getRight` and `getLeft` return  non-`const` references to `TreeNode`, but this is a bit dangerous as now anyone can use the returned `TreeNode` reference to wreak unholy hell on the tree without the tree being aware. You're going to have to rethink how you insert, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thanks a lot

Comment: hi sorry to bother you again here. The problem is I am getting segmentation fault where I am calling this `new` heap corruption possibly. Why `tn` goes out of scope once I call `new` ?